# Semantic UI Search Selection Dropdown with API.js - api call not happening

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

When debug mode is turned on for Semantic UI, I can see in the console the actions of the search selection dropdown, but I never see the api call when using the API.js/data-action="..." functionality of Semantic (I CAN see the API call if I attach a mock response directly to the search element).  Things are set up as follows:

HTML file:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/API.js"></script>
</head>
```

.......

```
<div class="ui search selection dropdown" data-action="lookup customer">
  <input type="hidden" id="id_customer">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Select a Customer...</div>
</div>
```

API.js file:

```
var api = {
  'lookup customer' : '/js/cust/{query}'
};
```

I also tried an alternative variation for the API.js declaration that I saw [in the docs](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#/usage):

```
$.fn.api.settings.api = { . . .
```

What am I missing?  Also, for the purpose of testing API.js functionality, is there a way to put mockResponses in the API.js file?  I've tried the following but get an "Unexpected token" message.

```
var api = {
  'lookup customer' : mockResponse: {
                    success: true,
                    results: [
                        {"custName":"Cust 1","data-id":1},
                        {"custName":"Cust 2","data-id":2},
                        {"custName":"Cust 3","data-id":3}
                    ]
                }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common use case for using data attributes with API is to have a single initialization in JavaScript power several different components with unique settings.

For example, lets say we want to have two separate dropdowns that use two different URLs for returning results.

One for retrieving customers and another for retrieving users. You might use something like this.

One thing to keep in mind, is that dropdowns will not query for a remote endpoint unless *some* API settings are specified. So passing a blank object, or an object with extended settings is necessary to trigger a remote call.

http://jsfiddle.net/056rvjas/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui search selection dropdown" data-action="lookup customer">
  <input type="hidden" id="id_customer">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Select a Customer...</div>
</div>

<div class="ui search selection dropdown" data-action="lookup user">
  <input type="hidden" id="id_customer">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Select a Customer...</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$.fn.api.settings.api = {
    'lookup customer': '/lookup/name={query}&type=customer',
    'lookup user': '/lookup/name={query}&type=user',
}


$('.ui.dropdown')
    .dropdown({
    apiSettings: {
        debug: true
    }
  })
;
```

Comment: That works except that I need to map the incoming JSON field names. (I'm getting results but they're showing as Undefined because of the lack of field mapping.) Is there a way to do field mapping in the metada? (I tried: <div class="ui search selection dropdown" data-name="company" data-value="id" data-action="lookup customer"> but it didn't work.) Or is there a way to do field mapping in the API.js file?  I want to use only the API.js and metadata for API calls, but if I can't do field mapping in either the metadata or API, then am I only left with attaching a handler directly on the object?